# Sum integer value fields of a dictionary in vb.net 4.0

Tags: .net, vb.net, dictionary

In .net 4.0 dictionary I know I can calculate the sum of all integer value field like this:

```
 Dim dbar As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)() From {{"A", 1}, {"B", 1}, {"C", 1}}
    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    For Each v As Integer In dbar.Values
      sum += v
    Next
```

Does exist a more elegant way to do calculate the sum?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the [`Sum()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338442.aspx) method:

```
dbar.Values.Sum()
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using LINQ to Objects:

```
Dim sum As Integer = dbar.Values.Sum()
```