# Error trying to sum values of a dictionary

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, sum

I'm trying to sum all values of a dictionary(of String, Boolean) as explained in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757825/sum-integer-value-fields-of-a-dictionary-in-vb-net-4-0) answer but I'm getting error:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Sum' accepts this
>   number of type arguments

I also tryed on .netFiddle with this:

```
Imports System.Linq
imports system.collections.generic

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim a as integer
        Dim Dic As new dictionary(of string, boolean) _
        from {{"First", 0},{"Second",0},{"Third",1}}
        a = Dic.values.Sum()
    End Sub
End Module
```

And get same error.
What am I missing?

EDIT:
I know that the code will work if I change my `dictionary(of string, boolean)` into a  `dictionary(of string, integer)` but I'd like to know if I can use `sum()` to check boolean values or not.

Comment: What do you want to sum here?  The key is a string and the value is a boolean. Do you want to know how many values are true?

Comment: @Steve Yes. And After I'll put all values into a string ("001")

Comment: @varocarbas I expect only what in the question-answer I found! Please see the link I posted before

Comment: (I deleted my comment because your reference is wrong; the linked post is fine) `Dic.Values` retrieves all the values in the dictionary (a set of booleans in this case); and `Sum` plainly adds all the elements in the resulting collection. Can you add booleans? (not unless casted/converted to integers). The referred post is adding integers!! PS: in any case, I do insist in the idea that SO posts are not absolute references of validity (much less when misinterpreted), just likely-to-be-valid. The absolute references are VS and the common sense.

Comment: Everyone makes mistakes and correcting them is usually the end of the story. On the other hand, you shouldn't hide the reality (what might provoke other problems to you/others). Your error comes from misunderstanding the basic differences among basic types (and, most likely, from having misused `Option Strict Off` which should only be used by people with a deep enough understanding of VB.NET). Asking why you cannot add booleans is very basic and, in my opinion, completely off-topic here (although I should have analysed your code properly anyway, what I didn't do in my first comment, sorry).

Comment: Just in case it is not clear: you were trying to add the items of a dictionary defined by two types (string and boolean) which cannot be added; that's why I was completely sure that you made a basic error even without analysing the code properly. I do apologise for my behaviour (tend to do this kind of things more than what I should; and do kind feel a bit bad about it. On the other hand, I am seeing so many off-topic behaviours here which shouldn't happen at all...), but hopefully you don't misunderstand it: if you write a proper-in-appearance question I will certainly analyse it properly :)

Comment: @varocarbas I think it's clear now: I changed my dictionary to `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)` to avoid more problems because I need to put numeric values into a string like "001". But I was happy to learn something else. Thanks again

Comment: No problem (happy to read that, although my efforts are mostly focused on future readers :)). Just one thing: if you need to put numeric values into a string why do you need a dictionary at all? Why not storing the values as strings (e.g., an array or a list) and converting them to numbers when required? (you have to make the conversion anyway at some point to make sure that they are actually valid numbers). Dictionaries are very nice, although are not precisely efficient collections; that is: use them only when required (and for small-enough sizes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum is not the correct method to use for counting how many entries are true in your dictionary. Sum requires an `integer` to act on. Your link works correctly because the dictionary has values of type integer, you have a boolean type.

If you want to count how many entries in the dictionary are true then you should use `Where` to enumerate the entries with `True` value and then `Count` the result

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim a as integer
    Dim Dic As new dictionary(of string, boolean) _
    from {{"First", 0},{"Second",0},{"Third",1}}
    a = Dic.Values.Where(Function(x) x = True).Count()
End Sub
```

or also

```
a = Dic.AsEnumerable().Count(Function(x) x.Value = True)
```

Notice that `x = True` and `x.Value = True` are not necessary. Writing `x` or `x.Value` is enough. Added here just to clarify the intentions

Comment: Very thanks for your answer! But I was asking: "why my code won't work if it's written as in the referenced answer?". Here I saw (as accepted) an answer to sum values of a dictionary(of string, Integer) . I also tryed to change my dic to dictionary(of string, Byte)  but I got the same error. This was my question.

Comment: @genespos I explained your mistake in my comment above: your dictionary is string and boolean and this codes gets all the values (in your case, a collection of booleans). You can add integers (what happens in the post which you are referring), but not booleans (unless being casted to integers)!

Comment: Yes, the problem is the Boolean part. Your code compiles just because you have Option Strict Off and this allows an implicit conversion between the values (0, 1) to booleans when you add the entries to the dictionary but Sum cannot automatically convert back the booleans stored in the dictionary to integers.

Comment: @varocarbas Thanks again to both. I am used to think to a boolean as 1/0 instead of True/False so this was the problem.

Comment: @genespos I am afraid that you rarely use `Option Strict On` (certainly recommendable for those whose ideas about VB.NET are not completely clear). You cannot do `Dim testBool As Boolean = 0` exactly the same that you cannot do `Dim testString As String = 1`. They are different types expecting different inputs. The similarity among them allows the less rigid rules to be applicable (e.g., casting rather than converting or being allowed with `Option Strict Off`), but this is not an excuse for misunderstanding them (relaxed rules are meant to be used only when a full understanding is present).